# How to log in where I left off

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, If I log in to the game, I log back in at spawn, which means that I have to find my way back into any cave I was in the middle of exploring when I left off. Is there any way to make it so that I log back in where I left off?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to log back in to where you previously were. Personally I find this quite useful, especially before you find a magic mirror, as sometimes it can be difficult to get back to spawn or your base.

Now one thing that I have done in the past to resume what I was doing previously, or to change where I respawn for a boss fight, is to make a rudimentary room with a bed in, so that I can respawn where ever I would like to.

Although it may be a pain to have to make a room every time that you want to leave the game when you want to preserve your location, this solution may be just the thing that you are after. For information regarding constructing a proper room, please refer to the official Terraria wiki.

Comment: They have wires and teleporter pads for a reason.. Other solutions exist to this problem (Which I allllmost agree with being a problem, because its a little too convenient for warping home :D)

Comment: I tend to use teleporters to get to key areas around the map, such as the dungeon, hell, or the lihzahrd temple. But they seem inconvenient for use when caving or exploring, as you would have to lay wires all the way there as you were going and that would be quite tedious. If the player hasn't beaten Skeletron yet, they won't be able to use teleporters anyways.

Comment: I always make little bases around where I go to often, including exploration locations... But then again I also generally make ice slide tunnels as well that I end up laying down wires to eventually make them even faster :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is one way. Find a bed. Next, build a NPC-fit house where you left off. Then, Place the bed, and right-click on it. It will set your spawn point at the NPC House.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a necro, but I recently made a mod that does exactly this.
[Player Location Saving](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/player-location-saving.87192/), available on the in-game Mod Browser, the [Mirror](https://mirror.sgkoi.dev/Mods/Details/PlayerLocationSaving), or [GitHub](https://github.com/Garretonzo/PlayerLocationSaving/releases).

I searched long and wide for such a mod, but wasn't able to find one. I am posting this for all the people who end up on these scattered threads after googling endlessly.